# Increment if statement arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-uno

I have a light connected to a x2 photo resistors connected to my Arduino I have them on a limit when they are grater than the limit it then carries out its command.

What I would like to do is make it more sensitive by having the sensor carry out its actions if say its value changes by say 5 in a single step rather than waiting for it to get to the limit.

Suggestions and a little help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int sensorPin1 = A5;
int sensorPin2 = A4;
int ledPin2 = 7;
int ledPin1 = 8;
int moto = 12;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(moto, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(sensorPin1, INPUT);
    pinMode(sensorPin2, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(moto, LOW);
}

int limit = 450;

void loop() {
    // read the value from the sensor:
    int sensorValue1 = analogRead(sensorPin1);
    int sensorValue2 = analogRead(sensorPin2);
    int sensorValue1a = analogRead(sensorPin1 - 2);
    int sensorValue2a = analogRead(sensorPin2 - 2);

    if (sensorValue1 > limit) {
        digitalWrite(moto, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
    }

    delay(0);

    if (sensorValue2 > limit) {
        digitalWrite(moto, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
    }

    Serial.println(sensorValue1);
    // delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sensorPin1 = A5;
int sensorPin2 = A4;
int ledPin2 = 7;
int ledPin1 = 8;
int moto = 12;
int sensorValue1last = 0;
int sensorValue2last = 0;

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(moto, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(sensorPin1, INPUT);
        pinMode(sensorPin2, INPUT);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(moto, LOW);
}

int limit = 450;

void loop() {

    // read the value from the sensor:
    int sensorValue1 = analogRead(sensorPin1);
    int sensorValue2 = analogRead(sensorPin2);
    int sensorValue1a = analogRead(sensorPin1 - 2);
    int sensorValue2a = analogRead(sensorPin2 - 2);
    int diff1 = sensorValue1-sensorValue1last;
    int diff2 = sensorValue2-sensorValue2last;

    if ( sensorValue1 > limit || diff1 > 5 ) {
        digitalWrite(moto, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
        sensorValue1last = sensorValue1;
    }

    delay(0);

    if ( sensorValue2 > limit || diff2 > 5 ) {
        digitalWrite(moto, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
        sensorValue2last = sensorValue2;
    }

    Serial.println(sensorValue1);
    // delay(100);

}
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. Perhaps use `sensorValue1last` and `sensorValue2last` to keep within the context of the OP's code. And more explicitly, set `sensorValue1last = sensorValue1` after each iteration.

Comment: I only have a single value at a time I am trying to log the value and then compare it after the change and then log the new value and so on. This code is going to compare it agents its current self no ?

Comment: Store your old value in the same way @polarysekt suggested

Comment: You'll want to declare sensorValue1last outside of your loop so that it's global and will persist after each iteration.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect the full code. Hopefully I didn't make any mistakes. Anyway, you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much I owe you a beer. I am new to this and it is a hobby I love but I have so much more to learn.

Comment: Glad to help. Check out http://hackaday.com/ if you haven't already. They have tons of great stuff for learning and inspiration. Happy hacking.